# Find and replace with nothing in MS Word

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, find-and-replace

How can I replace any word of specified size, color, text font... with nothing, i.e., I want to remove all the words with such criteria?

Answer (score 4):

In the find box, you put the information you wish to search, including font characteristics (size, color, font, ...). In the replace box, there is nothing; not even a space character. When you click on replace, it will find the information and delete it.